# Implementing a convolution integral symbolically using integration-by-parts

Tags: integration, convolution, symbolic-computation

I'm working on implementing a convolution integral symbolically (not numerically), to be used in a mathematical modelling tool. This is more of a mathematical problem at this stage, NOT programming. The convolution integral I am working with is truncated at some time $t$ and commences at $t = 0$ and is as follows:
$$
(f*g)(t) = \int_0^t{f(t-\tau).g(\tau).d\tau} \ \ [1]
$$

I've tried approaching this using integration by parts. However, I appear to be having difficulty since there are clear guidelines on using this for indefinite integrals but I couldn't find much for definite integrals. My approach involved the transformation of the $t - \tau$ term to some other variable $u$ which was then transformed back to $\tau$ without loss of generality.

The integration-by-parts formula is as follows (for any 2 functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$):
$$
\int{f(x).g(x).dx} = f(x).\left[\int{g(x).dx}\right] - \int{f'(x).\left[\int{g(x_1).dx_1}\right].dx} \ \ [2]
$$

Then, the worked-out method for a convolution integral should be as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
(f*g)(t) & = \int_0^t{f(t-\tau)g(\tau).d\tau} \\
& = g(t).\int{f(t-\tau).d\tau} - \int{g'(\tau).\left[\int{f(t-\tau_1).d\tau_1}\right].d\tau}  \ \ [3] \\ \\
& If \ we \ apply \ the \ following \ transform: \\
& Let, \ t - \tau = u \ \ [4]  \\
& Then, \ d\tau = -du \\
& And \ the \ limits \ become: \\
& @ \ \tau = 0, u = t \\
& @ \ \tau = t, u = 0 \\ \\
& If \ we \ flip \ the \ limits \ to \ ensure \ that \ it \ goes \ from \ 0 \ to \ t,\\
& the \ negative \ sign \ for \ the \ du \ term \ disappears \ i.e., \\ \\
& d\tau = du \\
& And \ the \ transformed \ limits \ become: \\
& @ \ \tau = 0, u = 0 \\
& @ \ \tau = t, u = t \\ \\
& A \ similar \ logic \ is \ used \ for \ the \ inner \ integral \ in \ the \ second \ term \\
& So, \ it \ transforms \ (t - \tau_1) \ to \ a \ new \ variable \ u_1 \\ \\
(f*g)(t) & = g(t).\int{f(u).du} - \int{g'(\tau).\left[\int{f(u_1).du_1}\right].d\tau} \ \ [5] \\ \\
& Assuming \ u \ is \ transformed \ to \ \tau \ without \ loss \ of \ generality, \\
(f*g)(t) & = g(t).\int{f(\tau).d\tau} - \int{g'(\tau).\left[\int{f(\tau_1).d\tau_1}\right].d\tau} \ \ [6] \\ \\
& The \ integral \ of \ f(\tau) \ and f(\tau_1) \\
& is \ essentially \ the \ area \ under \ the \ functions \ w.r.t. \ time \ (t) \\
& So, \ for \ function \ A_f(t) \ that \ defines \ area \ under \ f(t), \\ \\
(f*g)(t) & = g(t).A_f(t) - \int{g'(\tau).A_f(\tau).d\tau} \ \ [7] \\
\end{align}
$$

My input functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ that I'm using to test this approach are a square pulse and an ascending triangular pulse, respectively. They are as follows:
[image: Input functions for convolution]

And the result I obtain from this integration-by-parts method is as follows:
[image: Integration-by-parts convolution result]

This is incorrect, since the actual result should be something along the lines of this image, when I performed convolution in MATLAB (ignore the coordinates since I'm only using this image as reference for the overall shape):
[image: MATLAB results of convolution]

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me by pointing out where I might have made a mistake or suggesting alternatives to solve convolution integrals symbolically and not numerically.

Have a great day!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please number the formulas in your question if you want specific comments on the problems in your derivation of the integration-by-parts approach. Or you can perhaps determine where you went wrong by comparing your formulas with formula (4) in my answer below.

Comment: Done, equation numbers added. Thanks for pointing it out, @StevenClark! I won't be able to use equation 4, and I've included my reason in a comment to your post below (the transformed $(t-u)$ domain).

Answer (score 1):

For

$$f(\tau)=1-\theta(\tau-5)\tag{1}$$

and

$$g(\tau)=\frac{1}{5} (\tau-5)\, (\theta(\tau-5)-\theta(\tau-10))\tag{2}$$

corresponding to the recently updated figures in your question above then

$$h(t)=\frac{1}{10} (t-5)\, ((t-15)\, \theta(t-15)-2 (t-10)\, \theta(t-10)+(t-5)\, \theta(t-5))\tag{3}$$

which is illustrated in Figure (1) below, but I'm not sure I'd consider $h(t)$ a convolution integral since you're using $t$ both as a convolution variable and as an integration limit.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for h(t)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (3) for $h(t)$

---

Note the result illustrated in Figure (1) above is very different than the integration-by-parts method result illustrated in your answer above, but somewhat similar to but not exactly the same as the MATLAB result illustrated in your question above.

---

If you want to do a variable substitution in conjunction with integration by parts, I suggest you do the variable substitution first and then apply integration by parts as follows:

$$h(t)=\int_0^t g(\tau)\, f(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\int_0^t g(t-u)\, f(u)\,du$$ $$=\left.\left(g(t-u)\, \int f(u)\,du\right)\right|_0^t+\int_0^t \left(\int f(u)\,du\right)\, g'(t-u)\,du\tag{4}$$

---

In the case of your test functions $f(\tau)$ and $g(\tau)$ defined in formulas (1) and (2) above

$$\left.\left(g(t-u)\, \int f(u)\,du\right)\right|_0^t=0\tag{5}$$

and

$$\int\limits_0^t \left(\int f(u)\,du\right)\, g'(t-u)\,du$$ $$=\frac{1}{10} (t-5)\, ((t-15)\, \theta(t-15)-2 (t-10)\, \theta(t-10)+(t-5)\, \theta(t-5))\tag{6}$$

which leads to

$$h(t)=\frac{1}{10} (t-5)\, ((t-15)\, \theta(t-15)-2 (t-10)\, \theta(t-10)+(t-5)\, \theta(t-5))\tag{7}$$

which is equivalent to the result defined in formula (3) above.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Steven. Unfortunately, I'd like to figure out what's wrong with my integration by parts approach and not about alternate methods to solve a convolution. I'm unsure how your result comes about since the curve obtained in MATLAB is an output of how the convolution result changes over time, hence the upper integral limit of "t". This is also classified as convolution, not just if the limits include infinity or an integer. If you have any insights specific to the by-parts approach, I'd appreciate your comments/suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: @AjayMenon I don't understand the motivation for integration by parts as it seems to me it makes things more complicated than just directly evaluating the integral, but I'll take a look at your approach if I find time to see if I can determine where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you! The reason is that I want to symbolically represent convolution and one such approach that seemed to make sense was using the by-parts approach. I wish to apply it to a symbolic solver, and that means the integral needs to be represented in terms of symbolic variables and not numerically. I'm looking for a general symbolic solution. If you look at the equation at the end of my by-parts calculation, you will notice that it is completely symbolic and can be represented using a signals analogy. However, it provides incorrect results.

Comment: Steven, I was wondering if you had any ideas on how I could remove the $(t-u)$ term in the substitution by parts analogy. That should be my actual goal and I've only realized that lately. This is because the end mathematical solver I'm planning to use isn't capable of solving equations in a transformed domain, and everything is only defined in time $t$, meaning that $(t-u)$ cannot be processed. This is why it's important to have everything symbolically and exclusively in the $t$ domain. Thanks for your post, it's got me thinking in a new direction!

Comment: @AjayMenon I don't think you can get rid of the $(t-u)$ term resulting from the variable substitution as it's analogous to the $(t-\tau)$ in the original integral and related to the definition of a convolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect that you're right. I'd like to develop an alternate representation without this domain transformation, but all roads seem to be leading to the conclusion that numerical is the way to go with convolutions, not symbolic. Once again, thank you for the helpful suggestions! Have a good one